# Regular expression with Scrapy/Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, scrapy

with Scrapy I want to extract some data from websites. This is my section for the parsing:

```
item['title'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="box"]/h3/text()').extract()
item['date'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
item['text'] = sel.xpath('//span[@class="usercontent"]/p/text()').extract()
```

This works fine as intended. However, I want to restrict the second item only to dates with a regex (`\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d`). I follow the manual and write this:

```
item['date'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="date"]/text()').re(r'\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d').extract()
```

In this way it does not work. I get the following error:

> Error caught on signal handler: bound method ?.close_spider of
>   scrapy.contrib.feedexport.FeedExporter object at...

The regex works quite fine if I test it with the Shell. Any advice on this? Thanks a lot! I'm using Windows 7, 64 bit, Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

It's just that you don't need to call `extract()` after `re()` since `re()` returns a *list of unicode strings*:

```
item['date'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="date"]/text()').re(r'\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d')
```